# how to firing tag in specific place by GTM (google tag manager)?

Tags: html, google-tag-manager

Please i want to add ads at the end of the article so i asked the programmer to add div in this place and he add this code
 
in the place i want, but when i add the code of ads with this div in custom html at GTM the ads shows in footer not at end of article

Any body can help me to add the code correctly at GTM please.

Comment: You'll need to show us what code you already have.

Comment: Show us in the text of the question with an [edit]. Comments are not for question content, and they can be removed.

Comment: FYI, you need to add four spaces in front of your HTML code to avoid it being stripped off by SO. I'd done that in my edit but for some reason you reverted it.